# Save the data of current logged user in django

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I am a newbie in django and I have a question about how I can **save** and **show** **only** the data of logged user - since my application is multi-tenant.

**my view**

```
class ProjetoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Projeto
    fields = ['nomeProjeto',
              'descricao',
              'dtInicio',
              'deadline',
              'nomeSprint',
              'status',
              ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        logged_user = self.request.user
        return Projeto.objects.filter(User=logged_user)

class ProjetoList(ListView):
    paginate_by = 2
    model = Projeto
```

**my model**

```
class Projeto(models.Model):
    nomeProjeto = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    descricao = HTMLField()
    dtInicio = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    deadline = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    nomeSprint = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to Projecto model. Then, in your view, set `project.user = self.request.user` before saving your project model.

Comment: Ok, I added the line but I got the message "IntegrityError at /projeto/cadastrarProjeto/
NOT NULL constraint failed: projeto_projeto.user_id" . 

In my view I wrote  
def get_queryset(self):
        logged_user = self.request.user
        Projeto.user = self.request.user
        return Projeto.objects.filter(User=logged_user)

Comment: I believe that you can refer to object created by CreateView as `self.object`, so it is probably should be `self.object.user = self.request.user`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it completely wrong.

You shouldn't be using `get_queryset()` at all in `CreateView` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043478/4626254

Here's is what you can try instead.

1. Add a user field in `Project` model and apply migrations.
   `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
2. Create a class inheriting Generic `APIView` instead of `CreateView`.
3. Create a POST method like `def post(self, request):` inside that class and get all the details for creating a `Projeto` object in the request payload using `request.data` or `request.POST`.
4. Get the logged in user using `request.user`
5. Create a `Projecto` object with all this information as `Projeto.objects.create(**your_other_fields, user=request.user)`
6. Next time when filtering the objects, use a filter on `user` field like `user=request.user`.